# Read rule argument value from config file

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

Consider the following bazel rule written in a `WORKSPACE` file:

```
container_pull(
    name = "release-base",
    registry = "mydockernet:9443",
    repository = "release-base",
    digest = "sha256:...",
    tag = "1.8.2",
)
```

The problem is that the tag value `1.8.2` is written in a `yaml` config file and we want to respect the DRY principle (read the value from the config file instead of duplicating the value in bazel files). Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not yaml but you can define things in another bzl file and then load them into your WORKSPACE:

```
load("common.bzl", "MYVERSION")
container_pull(
   name = "release-base",
   registry = "mydockernet:9443",
   repository = "release-base",
   digest = "sha256:...",
   tag = MYVERSION,
)
```

then in common.bzl:

```
MYVERSION=1.8.2
```

Comment: Yes, we already know the solution with `bzl` files. The problem arises when the configurations are in a file that is not in Starlark format.